# Outer Join tables without foreign key using linq on NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Im trying to join two tables having a one to many relation but no foreign key.

Only one Order have Comments in this case.
I want all Orders and there Comments, if any.

```
SELECT O.OrderNo, O.OrderExpeditionDate, C.Comment 
FROM [Order] O
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderComment C
ON O.OrderNo = C.OrderNo
```

Result

```
OrderNo OrderExpeditionDate     Comment
----------------------------------------------
2222    2008-01-01              Comment 1
2222    2008-01-01              Comment 2
23232   1900-01-12              NULL
77      1900-01-01              NULL
```

How can I achive this in NHibernate using LINQ/fluent-NHibernate

Class Map:

```
public class OrderCommentMap : ClassMap<OrderCommen‌​t> 
{ 
  public OrderCommentMap() 
  { 
    Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Gu‌​idComb(); 
    Map(c => c.OrderNo); 
    Map(c => c.Comment); 
    Map(c => c.Comment2); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your `OrderComments` map class.

Comment: I'm NHibernate newbie, but I assume that this is what you are requesting.

    public class OrderCommentMap : ClassMap<OrderComment>
    {
            public OrderCommentMap()
            {
                Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
                Map(c => c.OrderNo);
                Map(c => c.Comment);
                Map(c => c.Comment2);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a navigational property to your `OrderComment` class:

```
public virtual Order Order {get;set;}
```

Then in your mapping replace `Map(c => c.OrderNo)` with:

```
References(x => x.Order).Column("orderno");
```

You then can use `Fetch` to create an outer join assuming you have a `Order` navigational property in your `OrderComments` class:

```
var results = session.Query<OrderComments>().Fetch(x => x.Order).Where(...);
```

Comment: Ok. So there is no way to do it without adding a reference if I want to use linq?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can use HQL or QueryOver to achieve the outer join.